# How to make Column child align at left while the other child align at right?

Tags: flutter

Hey I tried to build a chat app like this, and I have a hard time to align the time for each message. I want the chat bubble follow the size of the message, and the time is always on the right side of the message bubble.

[image]

Here is my current code for the message bubble:

```
Align(
    alignment: isMe ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: isMe
              ? BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(8))
              : BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(8),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(8)),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                offset: Offset(0, 4),
                blurRadius: 12,
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.04))
          ]),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 60,
                minWidth: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 20,
              ),
              child: Text(message)),
          ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              maxWidth: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 60,
              minWidth: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 20,
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Text(
                  sendAtTime,
                  style: textStyle.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 10, color: Color(0xff999B9D)),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 1),
                Icon(
                  Icons.check,
                  color: Color(0xffee3124),
                  size: 15,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Try removing the constraintBox once.

Comment: @KaranMehta it makes the time goes to the left side

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Align(
    alignment: isMe ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: isMe
              ? BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(8))
              : BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(8),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(8)),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                offset: Offset(0, 4),
                blurRadius: 12,
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.04))
          ]),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 60,
                minWidth: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 20,
              ),
              child: Text(message)),
          Row(
              mainAxisSize: double.infinity,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Text(
                  sendAtTime,
                  style: textStyle.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 10, color: Color(0xff999B9D)),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 1),
                Icon(
                  Icons.check,
                  color: Color(0xffee3124),
                  size: 15,
                )
              ],
            ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: do you mean MainAxisSize.max? cause double.infinity is returning error. It makes the container width follow the maximal width of the box constraint and not the content

Comment: Yes, remove the box constraint then it might get solved @ParamaArtha

Answer (score 1):

Try making,

```
Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "sendAtTime",
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.check,
                    color: Color(0xffee3124),
                    size: 15,
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

`mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` ensures that the children have maximum space between them.

Comment: The result that I want is like the first message bubble, but if the message long, the time and check icon move to the left (last message), what I want is the time and icon stay in the right side

Comment: remove all constraints and SizeConfigs, and also change `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,` to `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,` this should work

Comment: yeah it fix almost all the problem, but when the text message is smaller than the Row(), the text align will be on the end leaving blank space in the front